# Queue procedure call on same [main] thread

Tags: delphi

I am handling some specific TForm's event [**CMControlListChanging**],
and need to modify that (inserted) control, but thing gets *bad*, when I try to do so, because apparently it's not meant to do this in the **middle** of VCL operation.

So I need to **defer** that control modification, by **queuing** the code away from the [**CMControlListChanging**] handler, to be called at **later** time.

Sure, I can do **PostMessage** stuff, but I want more general approach.

System.Classes unit contains

class procedure Synchronize(ASyncRec: PSynchronizeRecord; QueueEvent: Boolean = False); overload;

which could do the trick, but it checks, whether
    CurrentThread.ThreadID = MainThreadID
 and if yes, then call  method I try to queue immediately.

Is the any *good* approach to **deferred** calls, at least on the main thread?

Comment: I'd be wondering if the problem could be solved without needing to defer.

Comment: Well, no
 I'm trying to implement TFrame children serialization, so I need to track down it's landing on form, and then call serialization proc, which restores edits, checks, combos, etc.

Comment: That already exists. I don't know but this smells funky to me.

Comment: I need to save-state serialization, I already have it working for main form, but not for dinamically inserted frames

Comment: Why you don't like the PostMessage? There is an example of how you can make it more general: https://github.com/zensan/pascal.today/blob/master/uProcQueue.pas
Other maybe does not like that..

Comment: Becasuse POSTMESSAGE is :
1. Not general solution, need to implement handler for each form
2. Not portable, where TThread.Synchronize looks portable
--
I want a library-level quality solution, if possible

Comment: I think the only alternative to `PostMessage` is `Application.OnIdle` handler. Synchronization staff is for background threads.

Comment: You do not need to implement it for each form/frame! The class is general.

Comment: You just write ProcQueue.Enqueue(procedure begin .... end);

Comment: Application.OnIdle handler -- well, I am as _smart_ as you.
But this is a bit lazy and slow. Go wonder, when it fires. You are always last in that queue.

Comment: With ProcQueue you are always in the predictable order.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but if you are on a recent Delphi version these *Postpone* methods may come in handy. They execute *AProc* in the main thread after applying an optional non-blocking delay.

```
uses
  System.Threading,
  System.Classes;

procedure Postpone(AProc: TThreadProcedure; ADelayMS: Cardinal = 0); overload;
begin
  TTask.Run(
    procedure
    begin
      if ADelayMS > 0 then begin
        TThread.Sleep(ADelayMS);
      end;
      TThread.Queue(nil, AProc);
    end);
end;

procedure Postpone(AProc: TThreadMethod; ADelayMS: Cardinal = 0); overload;
begin
  TTask.Run(
    procedure
    begin
      if ADelayMS > 0 then begin
        TThread.Sleep(ADelayMS);
      end;
      TThread.Queue(nil, AProc);
    end);
end;
```

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, indeed - thanks for the improvement.

Comment: @UweRaabe
Well, it's a solution that worked, and how ugly is it — create/utilize separate thread to do the job solely related to the main thread. Hope we get some better answer.

Comment: Does this approach ensure that the main thread code exit from the VCL operation (as author asked). What if the event handler code is longer then the time set for the delay? Will the code be executed before it should be executed for author goals?

Comment: @ZENsan Well, internally TThread.Queue utilizes PostMessage, so **yes**, even if adelayMS=0, handler already executed because it's synchronous, and the postponed method is queued.

Comment: @AlekXL. If you do procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TThread.Queue(nil,
    procedure
    begin
      ShowMessage('');
    end);
end;
then the message is shown even before the form is shown and other messages processed. or am i missing something?

Comment: @ZENsan, that's because you call Queue from inside the main thread. Use Postpone and it will work as expected.

Comment: @UweRaabe: Nice! When i needed to solve such problem I just faced similar issue. But this one is very nice-looking. Still will need to test it if it really works in the order as messages are processed, but anyway thanks!

Comment: @ZENsan Of course the methods are processed in order. It's just a call to `TThread.Queue` from a different thread. You know how `TThread.Queue` works.

Comment: It is really deeply frustrating that Emba won't give us a `TThread.Queue` that will `Queue` from the main thread. This does indeed behave as expected but it leaves a very bad taste in the mouth. Do Emba like to make us suffer?!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan right :) And I wrote some years ago that ProcQueue whcih actually can be changed from PostMessage to TTask.Run(). The only overhead is that for each queued procedure we have a thread created..

Comment: Ah right... there were no TTask before XE7. And I did not want to create a thread class etc.. But with tTask now it's really cool!

Comment: @ZENsan Actually, your ProcQueue is working, too, and it's better than the proposed answer _on_ _Windows_, especially because it can work on **any** thread with a msg pump, say, a thread with an Ics TWsocket worker. Probably you should add a conditional to your code — PostMessage stuff _on_ MSWin, and _TTask_ elsewhere. But why the heck don't you **const** all params in your class?

Comment: @AlekXL, thanks for your idea. I will adjust my implementation on GitHub.

Comment: @AlekXL const are just for compile check. And it does not affect the actual generated code.. or am I wrong?

Comment: @ZENsan If not sure, do const non-value types anyway,  wherever possible  — that's my advise. But Asyncs are refcounted, and objects are to be refcounted everywhere, this is imminent. So do the bleeding const.

Comment: @AlekXL, thanks for your note. I even did not know that. Just checked that. It really does not increment/decrement ref. count on a parameter if it is const! So for managed types const from now :)

Comment: FYI: [RSP-15427: Add an option to let TThread.Queue() run asynchronously when called by the main UI thread](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-15427)

Answer (score 0):

How about this one? It doesn't create a new task, just a new HWND (to receive the message):

```
TYPE TDelayedProc = REFERENCE TO PROCEDURE;

TYPE
  TPostponeClass        = CLASS(TWinControl)
                            CONSTRUCTOR Create(P : TDelayedProc);
                          STRICT PRIVATE
                            Proc        : TDelayedProc;
                            PROCEDURE   Run(VAR M : TMessage); MESSAGE WM_USER;
                          END;

CONSTRUCTOR TPostponeClass.Create(P : TDelayedProc);
  BEGIN
    INHERITED Create(NIL);
    Parent:=Application.MainForm;
    Proc:=P;
    PostMessage(Handle,WM_USER,0,0)
  END;

PROCEDURE TPostponeClass.Run(VAR M : TMessage);
  BEGIN
    Proc;
    Free
  END;

PROCEDURE Postpone(Proc : TDelayedProc);
  BEGIN
    TPostponeClass.Create(Proc)
  END;
```

It even works with anonymous methods, so you can postpone a part of execution of an event and still have access to the local variables (and the instance "Self").

Use it like this:

```
PROCEDURE WriteFile(CONST F : TFileName ; CONST STR : STRING);
  VAR
    TXT : TextFile;

  BEGIN
    AssignFile(TXT,F);
    IF FileExists(F) THEN APPEND(TXT) ELSE REWRITE(TXT);
    WRITELN(TXT,STR);
    CloseFile(TXT)
  END;

PROCEDURE TForm37.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  CONST
    N       = 'LOGFILE.TXT';

  VAR
    LocalVar : INTEGER;

  BEGIN
    DeleteFile(N);
    LocalVar:=20;
    Postpone(PROCEDURE
               BEGIN
                 WriteFile(N,'Postponed Code: '+Name+' ('+IntToStr(LocalVar)+')')
               END);
    WriteFile(N,'Last statement in event: '+Name)
  END;
```

The LOGFILE.TXT file will contain the two lines:

```
Last statement in event: Form37
Postponed Code: Form37 (20)
```

to illustrate that the postponed event is only run at the end of the event, as well as access to local variables.

Caveat: Do you run Application.ProcessMessages between Postpone call and event exit - if you do, the postponed code will be run at that point.

Answer (score 0):

Since Delphi 10.2 Tokyo, it is possible to defer a call from the main thread asynchronously using a method of `TThread`.

See [TThread.ForceQueue](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TThread.ForceQueue):

> ```
> class procedure ForceQueue(const AThread: TThread; const AMethod: TThreadMethod); overload; static;
> class procedure ForceQueue(const AThread: TThread; const AThreadProc: TThreadProcedure); overload; static;
> ```
>
> Queues the execution of a method call within the main thread.
>
> Unlike Queue, the execution of the method call specified by AMethod is forced to be queued although it is called by the main thread.
>
> AMethod associates the caller thread:
>
> - For static methods, you can associate the AMethod with any thread using the AThread parameter.
> - You can use nil/NULL as the AThread parameter if you do not need to know the information of the caller thread in the main thread.
> - RemoveQueuedEvents uses this thread information to find the proper queued method.